# Setting px width for table-cell

Tags: html, css

I am giving a width to a div with display table cell property but it is not working .

My code is

```
<header class="header layers">
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1 id="title"><?php echo $blogtitle;?></h1>
        </div>
</header>
```

And the css is

```
.layers {
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1040px;
}

.header {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

#title {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

But i don't know why it is not working this time i have used it many time with no problem . When i see the width of the wrap class in inspect element it is setting it to 100% with no error .
Please help . Appreciate any anwser and comment .

The fiddle link is this https://jsfiddle.net/yashag/zhsxLhzj/

Comment: Why not use `display: inline-block`? That will allow you to set a width.

Comment: Perhaps see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21130851/2397327)?

Comment: i want the h1 to float in the middle that why i set display table-cell

Comment: That's what [`display: flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is for.

Comment: how can i use flex for vertical align . Please tell

Comment: Yes. You can still [vertically-align](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809954/vertical-align-flexbox-vs-table-table-cell-on-elements-with-unknown-height), *and* you can [do more with it](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Give me a moment. I'll post an example as an answer.

Comment: @JonathanLam but flex isn't widely supported as far as I know. If you have to support old browsers.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix That was not a requirement. Anyways, [many modern browsers support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Comment: Then flex is a nice thing to play with! Yet on one project I had, I felt strange behaviour on different browsers (safari,chrome,firefox). Like mouse clicks not which would return strange mouseX, mouseY.

Comment: What are saying @Loic Faure-Lacroix Really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested in the comments, here is an example of using `display: flex` ([flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)) to vertically-align text (as you were trying to do with `display: table-cell`). You can also specify `width` and `height` of a flexbox easily, like a normal block element.

As you can see, the `display:flex` element correctly vertically-centers the text, *and* can be set to a `1040px` width correctly.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1040px;
}
div#centered {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="centered">Vertically-centered using <code>display: flex</code>.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Lam You are great

Comment: @YashAgarwal No problem! I'm glad I helped!